# Morphia default constructor and constructorArgs

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm using `morphia` as my mongodb odm.
I have a model `Car` with 2 required fields `plate` and `seats`.
I want to create a single constructor with those 2 parameters.

Morphia throws me an exception for not defining a default constructor.
I tried using `constructorArgs` annotation, but it failed.

All of the related threads I found didn't use the annotations and also didn't specify a suitable answer.

Comment: I don't know anything about Morphia, but if you want a constructor with two arguments, and if Morphia needs a default constructor, then you need 2 constructors, not 1.

Comment: can you try to use getter and setter ?? p.s. I don't know anything about Morphia as well

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to have an empty constructor, because the fields are mandatory. Morphia has an annotation named `constructorArgs` but I couldn't understand from their docs how to use it and what it does

Answer (score 2):

You need a no arg constructor for Morphia to work.  You can have this private and Morphia will work with it.  Morphia doesn't currently support constructor-based injection of properties but it's on the road map.

Comment: For the record, Morphia does now [support full constructors](https://morphia.dev/morphia/2.3/mapping.html#_constructors).  And in many cases, can support partial constructors and field/method based sets as well.